# Php get newest date

Tags: php, date, compare

I'm working in php and I have a list of dates in string format. I'd like to get the newest one, and have the function return it.. I can't seem to get this to work.. Maybe someone can help me out..

```
<?php
    $list_of_dates = array("04/17/1999 05:15 AM - CST", "04/17/2000 05:18 AM - CST", "04/17/2000 05:19 AM - CST");

    function getLatestDate($in){
        $ret = ""; 
        foreach($in as &$date){
         $cnt = strtotime($date);
         if(strtotime($ret) > $cnt){
            $ret = $date;
         }
        }

        return $ret;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition seems to be reversed:

```
if(strtotime($ret) > $cnt){
        $ret = $date;
     }
```

Should be:

```
if ($ret === '' || strtotime($ret) < $cnt){
        $ret = $date;
     }
```

You will want to overwrite `$ret` if its value is lower (older) than `$cnt`. In the first iteration `$ret` will be the empty string, so you will always want to overwrite that; of course, `strtotime('')` will probably always be lower than anything else, but it's good form to make the distinction.

Comment: It still seems that no matter what I do, it always returns the first entry in the array.. :/

Comment: @thefiscster510 Because your date format is wrong, see [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YGUr3O) for a working code.